# How to use stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have many stored procedures.
In order to use them I create a static class with static methods like this one:

```
public class DBHandler
{
    private static Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("db");

    public static DataTable GetItems(long filterId)
    {
        DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.P_GetItems");
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@filter_id", DbType.Int64, filterId);
        IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(command);
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        reader.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

As I wrote, I have many stored procedure and repeat this code is annoying.
Is there any better way to call stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the command line utility [`sqlmetal.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb386987.aspx) to auto generate the data context code that you can use in simple LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1):

Look into various DAL's out there. We have a home-grown solution that helps us wrap up IDisposable requriements for the connection, command, and reader objects. Also simplifies argument passing and conversion. But it's not rocket surgery - I'm sure there are many options out there.

Answer (score 0):

I like things like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SqlRetrieve(string ConnectionString, string StoredProcName, Action<SqlCommand> addParameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcName, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (addParameters != null)
            {
                addParameters(cmd);
            }

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                    yield return rdr;
            }
        }
    }
```

What you get here is a reusable enumerator (you could change this to return a table) which takes a delegate to provide the parameters.

In actual usage, it looks something like this:

```
foreach (var dr in 
        SqlRetrieve(cn, sp,
                    delegate (SqlCommand cmd) {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramname", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = someint;
                    }
        )
) {
}
```

So you aren't repeating all the same code, just the parameter parts.  In your case, if you are always returning DataTables instead of needing to get a lot of code in the DataReader loop, the code could get even simpler.